# Upgraded to TSC 2.0.0- node modules aren't resolved by VS Code syntax checker

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

## The Problem

[image]

- When importing NPM modules, VS Code fails to show import information about NPM modules. `[TS] Cannot find module 'lodash'/'react'/'etc'.`
- When importing an NPM module written in TypeScript (or one with a `typings` property in its `package.json`) I don't see this issue.
- WebPack still compiles with no issue, leading me to believe it is an  issue with VS Code or the Typings tool.

## Setup

I was running `tsc` 1.8 this morning. I upgraded to `tsc` 2.0.0 later.

VS Code 1.4.0 6276dcb0ae497766056b4c09ea75be1d76a8b679

Node 5.10.0

`tsc -v`: === "Version 2.0.0"

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Full project source code [here](https://github.com/RickCarlino/farmbot-web-frontend/tree/8904d81aba32dba6edaa41db85389d2763d41ef9). Disclaimer: it's a fairly large codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following to `/.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
}
```